# How to receive multiple values "Array" from POSTMAN application/json in raw form in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am having a little issue when I try to receive multiple array values in PHP for validation. I have this object with values in POSTMAN raw form, `application/json` :

```
{
  "name":"create_insert_new_delivery",
  "param":{
       "email_of_shipment_owner":"hi@example.com",
       "shipment_type ":"B",
       "item_name": ["50", "60"],
       "item_weight ": ["H", "I"],
       "item_length": ["70", "90"]
 }
}
```

When I try to receive **$item_name = $this->validateParameter('item_name', $this->param['item_name'], ARRAY, true);** like **the two strings below** are received I get this

**ERROR : **

> [04-Jul-2018 13:16:58 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected
>   ',', expecting '(' in
>   /home/osconliz/public_html/Osconlizapicall/api.php on line 304

The receiving code below.

LINE 302

```
$email_of_shipment_owner = $this->validateParameter('email_of_shipment_owner', $this->param['email_of_shipment_owner'], STRING, true);
```

LINE 303

```
 $shipment_type = $this->validateParameter('shipment_type', $this->param['shipment_type'], STRING, true);
```

LINE 304

```
$item_name = $this->validateParameter('item_name', $this->param['item_name'], ARRAY, true);
```

LINE 305

```
 $item_weight = $this->validateParameter('item_weight', $this->param['item_weight'], ARRAY, true);
```

LINE 306

```
$item_length = $this->validateParameter('item_length', $this->param['item_length'], ARRAY, true);
```

but the STRINGS are received properly :

```
public function validateParameter($fieldName, $value, $dataType, $required = true){
        switch ($dataType) {
            case BOOLEAN:
            if (!is_bool($value)){
                $this->throwError(VALIDATE_PARAMETER_DATATYPE, "Datatype is not valid for " . $fieldName . ' it should be boolean.');
            }
            break;
            case INTEGER:
            if (!is_numeric($value)){
                $this->throwError(VALIDATE_PARAMETER_DATATYPE, "Datatype is not valid for " . $fieldName . ' it should be integer.');
            }
            break;
            case STRING:
            if (!is_string($value)){
                $this->throwError(VALIDATE_PARAMETER_DATATYPE, "Datatype is not valid for " . $fieldName . ' it should be string.');
            }
            break;
            case ARRAY:
            if (!is_array($value)){
                $this->throwError(VALIDATE_PARAMETER_DATATYPE, "Datatype is not valid for " . $fieldName . ' it should be array.');
            }
            break;

            default:
            $this->throwError(VALIDATE_PARAMETER_DATATYPE, "Datatype is not valid for " . $fieldName);
            break;

        }

        return $value;
  }
```

After receiving I want validate data like this

```
    if ($this->item_category == ""){

          } else {


          if ($this->item_category == "A" || $this->item_category == "B" || $this->item_category == "C" || $this->item_category == "D" || $this->item_category == "E" || $this->item_category == "F" || $this->item_category == "G" || $this->item_category == "H") {

          } else {
            $this->throwError(INVALID_DATA_TTT, "Invalid item category");
           exit();  
          }
          }
```

Comment: Following the error, this has nothing to do with your logic and is just a `,` that is floating around somewhere. I haven't spotted it yet though.

Comment: @loek Thanks, but is it the correct way of receiving "$item_name = $this->validateParameter('item_name', $this->param['item_name'], ARRAY, true);" an array format.

Comment: @loek the previous lines before it present no syntax error

Comment: It's actually very logical, but I didn't expect it at all. See my answer.

Comment: @loek thanks for the answer but could you give an example cause I dont seem to grab "This is because ARRAY is an apparently case-insensitive function for creating arrays" especially this part "The easiest way to fix this, is to just pick another keyword I guess?" cause array is the receiving format just like th string listed above.

Comment: It means that you cant use the word "array" because PHP will always read it as a function to create arrays. You can replace it with anything but a keyword, like `ARRAYS` or `JSON_ARRAY` and it should work. Don't forget to change it in the switch statement as well.

Comment: @loek That solved it, but how do I then break down the array for validation I have made an update.

Comment: That's a different question entirely, please create a new post for that. Also consider to tag as answer so other people can benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `ARRAY` is an apparently [case-insensitive function](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) for creating arrays. See it here: https://3v4l.org/keu3K

The easiest way to fix this, is to just pick another keyword I guess?

**EDIT** - For reference, all the reserved keywords and functions in php: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php